# How to use a many2one field in Odoo 12?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, many-to-one, odoo-12

I have two class in python file (odoo version is 12):

```
class Module_procede(models.Model):
    _name = 'moduletest.procede'

    pr = fields.Char("firstname", default='???', required=True)
    mp = fields.Char("lastname", required=True)


class Module_procede(models.Model):
    _name = 'moduletest.prix'

    pr_ = fields.Char("firstname", default='???', required=True)
    mp_ = fields.Char("lastname", required=True)
```

How to make relation Many2one for field "pr_" like this:

```
pr = fields.Many2one(pr_)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Odoo Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.fields.Many2one) explain it well. You can check for some examples in the Odoo source code as well:

```python
class ModuleProcede(models.Model):
    _name = 'moduletest.procede'

    pr = fields.Char("firstname", default='???', required=True)

class ModulePrix(models.Model):
    _name = 'moduletest.prix'

    pr_ = fields.Many2one(
        string=_('First name'),
        comodel_name='moduletest.procede',
    )
```

If you want to get the opposite just move the `many2one` field to the other model